# Are there differents meanings of momentum (linear, angular or magnetic moment)?

Tags: magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, momentum, magnetic-moment

I'm really confused and exhausted to try to understand why we refer to magnetic moment as moment. The definition for momentum that I often seen is; "How much difficult is to the stop something that is moving", but with that in mind I can't see why we say *magnetic moment* instead of something else.

In a video about magnetic moment they say; "magnetic moment is a quantity which tells us about the strength of magnetic field that a particular object will generate". Considering the definition/concept of momentum that I mencioned; Would it be correct to say "magnetic moment is how much dificult is to move a particular object that generate a magnetic field because the work to move the object is also related to move the magnetic field"? And if that is correct, then the definition of magnetic moment would include the angular moment related to the mass and not only to the moving charge? Maybe that sounds silly if you think in particles, but what about the earth?

As I always say, sorry if my grammar or punctuaction is bad, but I'm not native and I try to do the best I can.

Comment: I have always been confused about this. A *moment* is often a number computed using a (mass, charge or probability) density distribution. Like a first moment is $\int x \rho(x) dx$, second moment $\int x^2 \rho(x) dx$ and so on. There might be a neat explanation for the nomenclature. I don’t know if it’s related to momentum at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name "moment" comes from the multipole expansion, which can be formulated several (equivalent) ways. One, for electrostatics, is as follows.

Suppose you have a charge distribution $\rho(\vec r)$, contained in some volume $||r|| \lt ||R||$, then outside of $||R||$, you can expand the potential into multipoles:

$$ \Phi(\vec r)=\frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0}
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-1}^l\big(\frac{Q_{lm}}{r^{l+1}}\big)\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$$

where $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ are the spherical harmonics. The distribution is completely described by its multipole moments:

$$ Q_{lm}\equiv \int{d\vec r'\rho(\vec r')(r')^l}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}}Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi')$$

Note that via $(r')^l$, the expressions are the $l-th$ moment of the charge distribution.

For a point charge, $q$, at $r=0$, the only non-zero moment is the monopole moment $Q_{00}$, and the potential is the Coulomb potential:

$$\Phi(r)=\frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac q r$$

An electric dipole, with dipole *moment* $\vec p$, is described by the 3 $Q_{1,0}, Q_{1,\pm 1}$, which captures its magnitude and orientation so that:

$$\Phi(r)=\frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac {\vec p\cdot\hat r} {r^2}$$

Then there are 5 quadrupole moments and so on.

With magnetism, there is no monopole moment, and the lowest order term is the magnetic dipole moment, which is often called "the magnetic moment". (For a spin 1/2 particle, it is the only allowed magnetic moment).

The term is unrelated to momentum, even though it is the 1st moment of the velocity for a mass distribution $\rho(r)$:

$${\vec p} =\int \rho(r)\vec vd^3r$$

Comment: It really seems more difficult than I thought. Thanks for answering.

Comment: No it's not. It simpler than you thought. Each power of $1/r^{l+1}$ potential comes from the $l-th$ moments of $rho$, for which there are $2l+1$ multipole-moment.  If you rotate the distribution, powers of $l$ do not mix (they're closed under rotations), so they represent something fundamental about geometry of the distribution. It's very much like using Fourier analysis to transform a time signal into frequency weights.

Comment: @rudellgosef btw: the integral for $Q_{lm}$ for a spherical shell is non-zero for only $Q_{00}$, which is why you can treat it as a point source, which is always a surprise introductory orbital mechanics. For something like the earth, which is flattened by rotation, all that information goes into $Q_{20}$,  which is called $J_2$ in aerospace (it's used to create sun synchronous orbits). Meanwhile, the "geoid" (EGM2008) is Earth's field out to $l=2159$, or $10'$ resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You see to be confusing [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)) and [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum). They are two different concepts.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the confusion.